# access to jquery methods on components within Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I'm using modals from bootstrap within my Aurelia application and would like to hide/show the modal from my view model. I can make it work by just using jquery in my vm as so:

`$('#myModal').modal('show');`

but would prefer a more "Aurelia Way" type method such as:

    `<div id="myModal" ref="myModal" ...>
        ...
    </div>`

and in the vm do this:

    `this.myModal.modal('show');`

however when i do the below I get just the DOM element with none of the prototype methods on it. How can this be achieved in Aurelia?

Comment: https://github.com/PWKad/aurelia-bs-modal

Comment: the example seems to be broken using bootstrap 3.3.6.. I've posted an issue for the author

Comment: I don't think this `$(this.modal).modal('show')` is the way to show the modal. Did you read how to use it? https://github.com/PWKad/aurelia-bs-modal#how-to-install-this-plugin The example shows  this `<modal show.bind="show">` and by changing the show property you either show it or hide it. But I'm not familiar with aurelia so i might be wrong tho.

Comment: Used as shown, but get an error with that line in the plugin so I tested it separate of the plugin and it definitely does not work.. The difference I'm seeing is that the context of the returned jquery object is different.. Not sure if it matters as I'm not familiar with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ref` binding command to your view.  This will give the view model a reference to the DOM element that is the bootstrap modal.

```html
<div ref="myModal" ...>
  ...
</div>
```

In your view model, `$(this.myModal).modal('show')` will show the modal.

You could also use the [aurelia-dialog plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog)

Comment: i tried this, and this is how it is done in the library linked above, but it fails saying method modal does not exist.